# Using KafkaStreams TimeWindows for detecting timeout and expiry

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, event-driven, stream-processing

Is it possible to use KafkaStreams TimeWindows to detect timeouts and expiries? Something that can be used in reservation/booking services. You reserve a table, then you have to pay for it fast enough. Otherwise you miss the reservation and you need to try again.
I want to send an event for the initial reservation, open a window on it and then get a state update when the window is closed.
The length of the window is the deadline to pay.
If a payment happens, another event will be published which updates the state of the window.
So at the end, I want a callback that happens when the window is closed and the latest state of the window at that point.

I have a POC implemented [here](https://github.com/bmd007/reactiveland/blob/main/experiments/event-only/cancel-reservation-on-payment-timeout/src/main/java/io/github/bmd007/reactiveland/KStreamAndKTableDefinitions.java).
Also described my idea in more details [here](https://medium.com/@bmd007/event-driven-solution-for-reservation-cancellation-due-to-payment-time-out-using-kafkastreams-98b8bef895ee).

And here is the summarised version of the code (where I probably went wrong).

```
        streamsBuilder.stream(Topics.CUSTOMER_EVENTS_TOPIC, EVENT_CONSUMED)
            .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), EVENT_JSON_SERDE))
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeAndGrace(Duration.ofSeconds(15), Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
            .aggregate(TableReservation::createTableReservation,
                    
                    (key, event, currentTableReservation) -> switch (event) {
                        case CustomerRequestedTable customerRequestedTable -> currentTableReservation.withTableId(customerRequestedTable.tableId())
                                        .withCustomerId(key)
                                        .withStatus(RESERVED_AWAITING_PAYMENT);
                        case CustomerPaidForTable ignored -> currentTableReservation.withStatus(PAID_FOR);
                        default -> currentTableReservation;
                    }
                    
                    , RESERVATION_LOCAL_KTABLE_MATERIALIZED)
            .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(new StrictBufferConfigImpl()))
            .toStream()
            .foreach((key, tableReservation) -> {
                log.info("final window state right before closure: {} ", tableReservation);
                LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.ofInstant(key.window().startTime(), ZoneId.of("Europe/Stockholm"));
                LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.ofInstant(key.window().endTime(), ZoneId.of("Europe/Stockholm"));
                log.info("window length {}:{}", startTime, endTime);
            });
```

I added `suppress` to only get one state update in the `foreach` block, only when each window gets closed. Unfortunately, what I get in the foreach block is kinda delayed.
And sometimes I don't get anything. It seems like I need to send another event (even with a different key) to the topic (which results in a new window), in order to get the result of the last window.

Also, when not using `suppress`, I'm not sure if I get all the state updates in the `foreach`, for each event.

So far I can detect that someone has paid in time. For that I get a state update in the `foreach` with status "PAID_FOR" which is terminal (even if I get it in the middle of the window).

But when I get "AWAITING_PAYMENT" in the `foreach`, I don't if it's terminal as I don't know if the window is actually closed.

Note: don't mind that strange switch. I'm using Java 21 preview features.